# Php Get keys of all items in array where value is equal to a specific constant

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like the one below:

```
$v = array(1,2,3,4,2,3);
```

How do I get the keys of all elements in array where the value is equal to 2?

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your answer to show what you tried so far so that we can help tweak your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a value in an array and you want to get the keys you can use [`array_keys()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the optional **`search_value`**:

```
$v = array(1,2,3,4,2,3);
$keys = array_keys($v, '2');
print_r($keys);

// Array
// (
//    [0] => 1
//    [1] => 4
// )
```

For the output check https://3v4l.org/N8EBH

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
<?php
$v = array(1,2,3,4,2,3);
$keys = array();
foreach($v as $k=>$x)
{
  if($x == 2) 
    $keys[] = $k;
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($keys);echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$v = array(1,2,3,4,2,3);
$a = 2;

$key = array();
foreach($v as $k=>$val)
{
    if($a == $val)
    {
        $key[] = $k;
    }
}

print_r($key);
```